# Is there a way to speed up the 100 hours required for ranked games?

Tags: dota-2

I started to play Dota 2 again for a couple of months. I only reached 35 / 100 hours to play the ranked games. I find that in unranked there are a lot of low quality games and it's not so much fun if you don't see your rank / mmr / commends. Is there a way to speed up the process of aquiering 100 hours for ranked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully there is no such thing.
These 100 hours are set to prevent new players from getting into ranked way to early (for their own sake).

But if you're an old Dota 2 player, I agree that this should be easier if you're just coming back.

Valve should implement something, like linking your old account with the new one or at least prove somehow that you know the game so you have to play fewer games than a 100 to be able to join ranked again.
But we all know old lazy Volvo.